# Shutdown blocked by app

Tags: shutdown

The shutdown process is blocked up to for a minute after running a Qt application.
I know, it is not possible to identify the problem solely on that information, but is there any way to investigate further?

Comment: Investigating crashes and errors should start with logs. dmegs and syslog are good way to start, but read the one with 0 in filename, as those have info from previous shutdown. Those without number show log that is for current boot. Among other things, you could try to use `pkill programname` , `xkill` to force the appliation to exit, if you wish so